# Difference between 'carbon footprint' tag and 'greenhouse-gas-emissions'?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two related tags that I feel overlap largely but IMHO are distinct enough to keep them as separate tags; [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint) and [greenhouse-gas-emissions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gas-emissions). Assuming other people agree the tags are not synonyms, my suggestion is to make it more clear when to use each tag by improving the tag usage guidance description for both tags (the excerpt that appears if you hover on the tag on the main site).

Currently the tag description for [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint) is 
"*a measure of the total amount of greenhouse gas emissions produced directly and indirectly by a person, an organisation, an event or a product.*"

[greenhouse-gas-emissions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gas-emissions) doesn't have a tag wiki yet.

Any suggestions? For what kind of questions should people use the carbon-footprint tag and for what questions the greenhouse-gas-emissions tag?

Answer (score 4):

This is a hard thing to categorise. The topics intersect somewhat and the tags are currently used interchangeably.

It might be worth renaming [greenhouse-gas-emissions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gas-emissions) to just [greenhouse-gas](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gas) (or [greenhouse-gases](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gases)?), and have it be a tag that categorises questions *about* gases but not necessarily about emissions, like the following:

- [How much does the methane content of natural gas vary, and what is the impact?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9842/8232)
- [Which gases increase the greenhouse effect more than carbon dioxide?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/83/8232)
- [How much of the emitted CO2 is human caused](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2339/8232)

That way, questions about the emission of GHGs could fall under [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint). A 'carbon footprint' is a measurement of emissions that boils them down to a single number (CO2 equivalent). It's meant to be an 'at-a-glance' indicator of how high (or low) an impact a particular individual, business, event or product has on the environment. As such, the sorts of questions tagged [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint) would be:

- How to **assess, estimate, measure and/or quantify**, emissions, product life-cycles, or other carbon-generating processes that would factor into a carbon footprint. For example:

  - [How would you calculate carbon emissions of software?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9891/8232)
  - [Is a solar cell phone charger a sustainable choice?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6900/8232)
  - [With current technology, how much CO2 is emitted when making renewable power plants?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/8307/8232)
  - [Why is the per capita CO2 emissions so much higher in Wyoming than in the Northeast?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6702/8232)
- Ask for **comparisons** of alike sources of carbon, e.g comparing the footprints of different sized households, transport options, products (clothing, furniture etc) and so on. Examples:

  - [Which has a smaller footprint -- canned or frozen vegetables?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6353/8232)
  - [Carbon footprint of CNG vs. Diesel as a vehicle fuel](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5919/8232)
  - [What type of cheese has the lowest carbon footprint?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5903/8232)

---

The excerpts for both tags could then look like:

[carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint)

> a measure of greenhouse gas emissions produced directly and indirectly by a person, an organisation, an event or a product. Questions about measurements, data, emissions or emission sources should use this tag. Use [greenhouse-gases] if your question is about a particular gas. Use the [global-warming] tag for questions about the effects.

[greenhouse-gases](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gases)

> Gasses that contribute to global warming by trapping radiant heat from the sun in the atmosphere. Use this tag for questions about certain gases and their effects. Use [carbon-footprint] for questions about measuring emissions from a person, organisation, event or product. Consider [global-warming] for questions about the effects.

What do you think?

Comment: This is a difficult one to untangle but I think you're on the right track. Another possible name for greenhouse-gas would be greenhouse-effect, as long as we're careful that questions are more relevant here than on Earth Science.SE or Physics.SE. It's also worth noting that not all greenhouses gases are carbon-based. Nitrous oxide is one example. Your tag excerpts seem to cover that well enough.

Comment: I like this proposal! I noticed we also have a co2 tag, but as with greenhouse-gases we could keep it for questions specific about carbon dioxide not related to a footprint. If this post gets a few more upvotes I will rename the greenhouse-gas-emissions tag. @Nic Personally I'm not in favor of renaming to greenhouse-effect primarily because we already have a global-warming tag and a climate-change tag

Comment: @THelper We also have a straight [tag:emissions] tag, which should probably be merged with [carbon-footprint] if we're going with the above suggestion :)

Comment: @Robotnik good point. Looking at the 2 questions with this tag we could also replace it with [tag:co2] for [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/8265/99) and [tag:air-pollution] for the [other question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/7130/99)?

Comment: Yeah makes sense to me 

Answer (score 1):

For [greenhouse-gas-emissions](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gas-emissions), riffing on the description for [carbon-footprint](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carbon-footprint), how about this:

> For questions about direct greenhouse gas emissions produced by a product, process, or facility (such as a factory or power plant).

Comment: Interesting definition, but I'm not sure I agree with the 'A measure of' part. I see greenhouse-gas-emissions more as a concept; all emitted gases that contribute to climate change.

Comment: So perhaps that's the main difference here; the carbon-footprint tag is primarily for questions related to measuring or quantifying GHG emissions, and greenhouse-gas-emissions tag is for other, more-general questions about GHG emissions (that do not involve measuring or quantifying impact).

Comment: @THelper that makes sense -- I edited with that feedback.